# Compiling and running a Windows Store 8.0 & 8.1 app with the Parse dll

Tags: .net, unity-game-engine, windows-store-apps, parse-platform, async-await

For the last day or so I have been trying to compile and run a Unity game for the Windows Store 8.0 & 8.1 with Parse as a back-end.

I can build it from Unity, and open the generated solution in Visual Studio (both 2012 and 2013) but building it from within here produces an error in the form of: `CSC : error CS0656: Missing compiler required member 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Task'`
 **when the Parse DLL is included**. It also complains about the usage of the 'async' and 'await' keywords in the MainPage.xaml.cs.

I have also installed the NuGet package, Microsoft.Bcl.Async, hoping that would be the solution.

I am working on the Windows 8.1 Pro OS and I can successfully build and deploy to the Windows Phone 8 and PC.

Has anyone here had the same issue and found a solution?

Comment: You shouldn't need `Microsoft.Bck.Async` for Windows Store apps. But that's not the same as for Windows Phone 8, which requires `Microsoft.Bck.Async`. What exactly is the target you're trying to build to?

Comment: I am trying to build it for both of these platforms. And regardless of whether the `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` is installed, I still get the same issue.

Comment: If create a new project, does the same happen? If you remove the Parse dll the problem disappears? Have you opened the Parse dll in iladasm.exe to see what are its dependencies?